# Delay delete SQL transactions in an SQR

Tags: peoplesoft, sqr

I am wondering if there is a way to delay Delete transactions in an SQR program? I am having an issue where I am deleting data from a table that has a trigger on it that inserts rows into another (Audit) table and the only key on the table that can be altered is a date/time stamp, but because these transactions are occuring at the exact same time (down to the hundreth of a second) it is causing duplicate insert errors on the sql trigger. I was hoping if there is a way to delay each row to be deleted in SQR that would be a good work-around to this issue. Thanks!

```
BEGIN-PROCEDURE DELETE-PSROLEUSER-ROLES

SHOW 'BEGINNING DELETE-PSROLEUSER-ROLES'

BEGIN-SQL
DELETE PSRO
FROM PSROLEUSER PSRO
INNER JOIN PS_GH_AD_X_WALK B ON B.OPRID = PSRO.ROLEUSER
INNER JOIN HRDEV01_FOR_BUDGET_MODULE.HRDEV92B.dbo.PS_JOB C ON C.EMPLID = B.GH_AD_EMPLID AND B.GH_AD_EMPLID <> ''
WHERE C.EFFDT = 
(SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM HRDEV01_FOR_BUDGET_MODULE.HRDEV92B.dbo.PS_JOB A_ED 
WHERE C.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID 
AND C.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD 
AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
AND C.ACTION = 'TER'
END-SQL

END-PROCEDURE DELETE-PSROLEUSER-ROLES
```

Comment: Maybe Oracle itself has a delaying tactic, but it looks like you are deleting multiple records with the one delete statement.  SQR itself doesn't control really what's in the BEGIN-SQL clause so it would be up to Oracle.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the code could be 'un-bulked' so that each SQL Delete is sent to the database server seperately, as oppsed to being bulked together.

Comment: You would have to manually find all the keys, for example in a Begin-Select Clause, then individually delete each one with the proper keys.  Bit of work but that way you could separate them out - perhaps even put a fake "WHILE" loop to count a few milli-seconds between each transaction

Comment: Yes I'm wondering if using a SQL cursor may help deal with this. The table really should have an additional key on it but I'm just to work around that instead of altering the structure.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you change to a cursor to do row-by-row processing, performance will suffer. Round-trips to the database are costly, and if you're deleting a lot of rows, it will be a lot slower.

Answer (score 0):

Please move all of the inner joins to the where clause for the delete.  You probably don't intend to delete rows from these inner joined tables, some of which may return multiple rows for an emplid.